# Unable to see credentials being sent from Android App to Ipcamera during packet capture on monitor mode

Tags: ip-camera, packet-capture

## Initial Setup

IP Cameras needs stable internet(say home WIFI) to stream live footage to user anywhere in the world. 
In order to provide wifi credentials (SSID & Password), we need to connect to IP Camera's hotspot (which is created initially), then open IPCamera's Android app and then provide ssid and password. Once credentials are acquired, IP Camera closes its hotspot and connects to the WIFI.

## Question

I am trying to sniff the packets (UDP) which contains this credentials (SSID and Password). I tried `tcpdump` on Android device and I am able to fetch these packets which contain credentials. `SSID and Password visible in clear text`. BUT when I try to capture same packets using `wifi dongle (with monitor mode enabled)`, I am unable to see this packet.

Why am I not able to see this packet in monitor mode ?

## Important things already taken care of :

- I have made sure that Wifi dongle being used supports monitor mode.
- Sniffing packets on monitor mode was done simultaneously while capturing packets on Android device.

I can provide packet captures if anyone wants to have a closer look. In both packet captures, I am able to see same source and destination ports, which means packet capture is successfully done in monitor mode.

Comment: This is a good question, but is it related to a programming language? If not, this would be better suited for networkengineering.stackexchange.com. If have relevant packet captures, post a link to them in your question, regardless of forum.

Comment: @RossJacobs - I have posted there too but no response. So looking forward to get some expert advice here.